# How do I group hourly data by day and count only values greater than a set amount in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, group-by

I am new to Pandas but have been working with python for a few years now.

I have a large data set of hourly data with multiple columns.  I need to group the data by day then count how many times the value is above 85 for each day for each column.

example data:

```
date                     KMRY  KSNS  PCEC1  KFAT                                          
2014-06-06 13:00:00  56.000000  63.0     17    11
2014-06-06 14:00:00  58.000000  61.0     17    11
2014-06-06 15:00:00  63.000000  63.0     16    10
2014-06-06 16:00:00  67.000000  65.0     12    11
2014-06-06 17:00:00  67.000000  67.0     10    13
2014-06-06 18:00:00  72.000000  75.0      9    14
2014-06-06 19:00:00  77.000000  79.0      9    15
2014-06-06 20:00:00  84.000000  81.0      9    23
2014-06-06 21:00:00  81.000000  86.0     12    31
2014-06-06 22:00:00  84.000000  84.0     13    28
2014-06-06 23:00:00  83.000000  86.0     15    34
2014-06-07 00:00:00  84.000000  86.0     16    36
2014-06-07 01:00:00  86.000000  89.0     17    43
2014-06-07 02:00:00  86.000000  89.0     20    44
2014-06-07 03:00:00  89.000000  89.0     22    49
2014-06-07 04:00:00  86.000000  86.0     22    51
2014-06-07 05:00:00  86.000000  89.0     21    53
```

From the sample above my results should look like the following:

```
 date           KMRY  KSNS  PCEC1  KFAT   
 2014-06-06     0     2     0      0    
 2014-06-07     5     6     0      0
```

Any help you be greatly appreciated.

```
(D_RH>85).sum()
```

The above code gets me close but I need a daily break down also not just the column counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to make `date` a DatetimeIndex and then groupby the result of the comparison to 85.  For example:

```
>>> df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) # only if it isn't already
>>> df = df.set_index("date")
>>> (df > 85).groupby(df.index.date).sum()
            KMRY  KSNS  PCEC1  KFAT
2014-06-06     0     2      0     0
2014-06-07     5     6      0     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I had the dates set as indexes already the last part is what I needed.